# Find a date and clear contents underneath target cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a macro that loops through one column that holds dates from old to more recent. It finds every date  that is greater than `Now` then goes to its adjacent cells and clears them.

I believe it could be much faster if the macro wouldn't loop against all values in the column (500 rows) but instead stops at the first cell match, then goes to its adjacent cells and clears all contents from that row till the bottom of the table (i.e. if the match is at row 15, then clear contents from row 15 all the way down to 500) without checking every row.

```vb
    Dim R As Long

    For R = 1 To 500
        If Cells(R, "A").Value >= Now Then Cells(R, "B").Value = ""
        If Cells(R, "A").Value >= Now Then Cells(R, "C").Value = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B" & Application.Match(Now,Range("A:A"),1) & ":C500").ClearContents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your methodology, if you want to know how to drop out of a loop once the criteria are matched - you would use an `Exit For`. You also can clear column B and C at the same time, like so:

```
Dim R As Long
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For R = 1 To 500
      If .Cells(R, "A").Value >= Now Then
          .Range("B" & R & ":C500").ClearContents
          Exit For
      End If
    Next
End With
```

In the above, I've also added reference to the sheet. This is always good practice to prevent possible errors once more than one sheet is available.

Comment: An additional comment that CLR's answer demonstrates:

Whenever possible you want to perform any operation exactly *once*. Avoiding multiple IF statements that check the same thing will improve performance. It probably doesn't matter here, but it's a good habit to get into.

Also: by checking a value once and then performing the steps as a group you reduce the chances of a problem occurring if you need to change the criteria (e.g. if you needed to clear dates starting from last week instead of from today, you could just change the IF in one place).

Comment: Also also: if your list is only 500 items it probably doesn't matter, but when you're dealing with very large sorted lists it's a good idea to do a binary search to find the key value. I'll include an example below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a binary search.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClearByDates(Optional targetDate As Variant = Null)

  Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim activeRange As Range
  Dim lowerRow As Long, higherRow As Long, thisRow As Long
  Dim thisDate As Date

  ' If no date is provided, assume today is the cutoff

  If IsNull(targetDate) Then targetDate = Date
  ' Assuming that we're putting this code in the worksheet that you want to _
    clear. If you decide to put it in a separate module you can either: _
      (1) Pass in the worksheet you want to modify as an argument, or _
      (2) Explicitly set the worksheet you want to modify using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Name)

  Set thisSheet = Me
  Set activeRange = thisSheet.UsedRange
 
  With activeRange
  ' Not only is it cleaner if you use With, you get better performance in VBA _
    because it's a hint that the object should be kept loaded and ready.

  ' Getting the range of rows with values
    lowerRow = .Rows(1).Row
    higherRow = lowerRow + activeRange.Rows.Count - 1
   
  ' Don't start processing until you're in the date range; _
    this should handle most common worksheet header situations.
    Do Until IsDate(activeRange.Cells(lowerRow, 1))
      lowerRow = lowerRow + 1
      If lowerRow > higherRow Then Exit Sub
    Loop
   
  ' Use a binary search to find the first row where the date is _
    greater than or equal to the target date.
   
    Do Until lowerRow >= higherRow - 1
      thisRow = (higherRow + lowerRow) / 2
      thisDate = .Cells(thisRow, 1)
      Debug.Print "Row " & Right("      " & thisRow, 7) & ": " & Format(thisDate, "YYYY-MM-DD") & " ";
      If thisDate >= targetDate Then
        Debug.Print ">= " & Format(targetDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
        higherRow = thisRow
      Else
        Debug.Print "<  " & Format(targetDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
        lowerRow = thisRow
      End If
      Debug.Print " (lowerRow = " & lowerRow & ", higherRow = " & higherRow & ")"
    Loop
 
  ' Assuming we just want to clear columns B & C. This can easily be adjusted _
    to clear all columns to the right by using .Columns(.Columns.Count) in the _
   ending range.
  thisSheet.Range("B" & thisRow & ":C" & .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row).ClearContents
 
  End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and information all solutions work, i opted for CLR solution as it is the simplest to follow , will prob move over to C.wihtes once i am sure i fully grasp it